# NSFileVersion: resolve conflict by copying file

Tags: objective-c, nsfilecoordinator, nsfileversion

I have NSFilePresenter for the entire Documents folder. I used to put files in iCloud container and if files were created at the same time on multiple devices, they were automatically renamed by iCloud. At the same time `presentedSubitemAtURL:(didMoveToURL:` would notify me that certain file created on certain device was renamed. It's important because it's the only way I know that files are being automatically moved by iCloud.

However, now I started resolving conflicts myself and implemented `- (void)presentedSubitemAtURL:(NSURL *)url didGainVersion:(NSFileVersion *)version` because I don't always want iCloud to simply rename files, sometimes I want to write in-place.

What is the proper way of separating conflicting versions of the same file onto two files in the same fashion as iCloud does? So if both devices wrote `file.txt` at the same time, I want one of files to be moved to `file 2.txt`.

So far I have the resolution that picks up the most recent version of file.

```
- (void)presentedSubitemAtURL:(NSURL *)url didGainVersion:(NSFileVersion *)version {
    // bail if no conflicts
    if(!version.isConflict) {
        return;
    }

    // get all conflicts
    NSArray* conflictVersions = [NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:url];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(modificationDate)) ascending:NO];

    // sort by recency
    conflictVersions = [conflictVersions sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]];

    // pick the most recent version
    NSFileVersion *recentVersion = conflictVersions.firstObject;

    // replace current item with the most recent version
    NSError *replaceError;
    if(![recentVersion replaceItemAtURL:url options:0 error:&replaceError]) {
        return;
    }

    // mark all conflicts as resolved
    for(NSFileVersion* fileVersion in conflictVersions) {
        fileVersion.resolved = YES;
    }

    // clean up other versions
    NSError *removeError;
    if(![NSFileVersion removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:url error:&removeError]) {
        return;
    }
}
```